# How to detect if a control is a hyperlink in MS Access vba

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink, vba

I am cycling through the controls on a form using

```
For Each ctl In frm.Controls
```

in Access VBA and would like to detect if a control is a hyperlink. I want to detect if the if the control is a hyperlink. I cannot see ControlType that matches with Hyperlink. I am assuming it is a text box with additional properties.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thank you in advance

Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check the length of the HyperLinkAddress property:

```
    Dim c As Control
    For Each c In Controls
        If Len(c.HyperlinkAddress) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print c.Name & " is a hyperlink (Address: " & c.HyperlinkAddress & ")"
        Else
            Debug.Print c.Name & " is not a hyperlink"
        End If
    Next
```